# Не открывается проект в NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image]

В общем, хочу я создать лаунчер для своего проекта в майнкрафт. Хочу запустить свой проект, и после этого должен открыться лаунчер, но он не открывается. Внизу мне прописывается причина этого(красным выделил). Переводил это дело в интернете, но не особо понял, в чём проблема.  Может быть кто-то знает и понимает это? Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Вам же написали - ошибка на 31 строке файла `MainClass.java`

Comment: а что это означает?

Comment: Это означает, что нужно открыть файл `MainClass.java` перейти на 31 строку и посмотреть из-за чего ошибка

Comment: скрин добавил, что же там не так, блин...

Comment: Лучше бы вы код добавили

Comment: а как его показать? что нужно нажимать? Извините, я не понимаю :(

Comment: Скопировать в редакторе и вставить в вопрос

Comment: я имею в виду, что не знаю как этот код открыть или увидеть. И что за редактор? Это нельзя сделать прямо в NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке у вас возникает ошибка `NullPointerException` и возникает она на 31 строке файла `MainClass.jave`. Это значит, что на этой строке происходит манипуляции с объектом, который равен `null`.

На этой строке у вас написано

```
stream.close();
```

99%, что `stream` равен `null`. Соответственно попытка вызвать метод у `null` приводит к исключению.

Переменная `stream` у вас инициализируется на 19 строке

```
InputStream stream = Starter.class.getResourceAsStream("/net/launcher/theme/favivon.png");
```

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) к методу `getResourceAsStream()` сказано

> **Returns:**
>   A InputStream object or null if no resource with this name is found

Или в переводе

> **Возвращает:**
>   Объект InputStream или null если ресурс с таким именем не найден

Вот вам и ответ.

1. Программа не нашла ресурс `/net/launcher/theme/favivon.png`
2. Вы сразу не проверили полученный результат
3. Вы получили `NullPointerException` когда попытались обратиться к объекту

Comment: Хм, благодарю :) А как эту проблему решить? Дело в том, что я порылся в папках и нашёл у себя этот ресурс favicon.png(тот ресурс, который программа не могла найти)

Comment: Проблему решил, большое спасибо Вам за помощь, терпение и понимание :))))

Comment: @Даниил Тогда отметьте мой ответ как верный